# How do I make a bootable USB flash drive that can run memtest?

Tags: linux, usb, bootable-media, usb-flash-drive, memtest86+

It seems that the canonical instructions for making a bootable USB flash drive that runs memtest are at:

http://forum.canardpc.com/showthread.php?t=28875

However, after following them to a T, I boot up the new machine and get:

"could not find kernel image: linux"

Do I need to set up a lilo.conf first?

Answer (score 6):

Download [System Rescue CD](http://www.sysresccd.org/) follow the instructions [USB stick](http://www.sysresccd.org/Sysresccd-manual-en_How_to_install_SystemRescueCd_on_an_USB-stick).

Boot from the USB, press F2 then type memtest

Comment: On UEFI systems, you need to get them to boot the USB stick in MBR / BIOS mode for it to give you the menu that includes the virtual floppy (memdisk) that includes memtest86+.  (The USB stick instructions result in a stick that can be booted as UEFI or as MBR.)